# Bresenham's line function C

Tags: c, line, keil

I am trying to implement Bresenham's line algorithm in c, the wikipedia simplified version.
My code gets stuck to an infinite loop and i cannot figure out why! (While im pretty sure it has to do with my c knowledge)

```
void Draw_line (unsigned int x0, unsigned int y0,unsigned int x1, unsigned int y1)
{
    unsigned int dx = abs(x1-x0);
    unsigned int dy = abs(y1-y0);
    signed short sx,sy;
    signed int err,e2;

    if (x0 < x1) {sx = 1;} else {sx = -1;}
    if (y0 < y1) {sy = 1;} else {sy = -1;}
    err = dx-dy;

    while (!(x0==x1 && y0==y1))
    {
        GLCD_PutPixel(x0, y0);
        e2 = 2*err;
        if (e2 > -dy) 
        {
            err = err - dy;
            x0 += sx;
        }
        if (e2 < dx) 
        {
            err = err + dx;
            y0 += sy;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: The conditional of the loop was wrong so it did not plot straight lines, changed it to the correct one.

Comment: http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Bresenham%27s_Line_Algorithm

Comment: best way to debug a code when you don't know any other technique is add printf statements.

Comment: Your code should work if you use signed integers throughout.

Comment: Enable all warnings from the compiler (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` if you're using gcc). Then fix all potential problems in your code that the compiler warns about.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your solutions, it was indeed the signed integers. I am coding on an embedded platform, thats why i couldnt debug it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that `dy` is an unsigned value so `-dy` is positive (and likely quite large) still (not negative). removing the unsigneds should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

After accept answer.

Changing to signed integer does *not* solve the problem in the *general* case, but may have solved it in @OP's limited case.

Changing to `int` works so long as the x,y points are not in the extreme range as obviously the below overflows (UB) for all sorts of large values of `x0,x1` as `int` or `unsigned`.

```
int dx = abs(x1-x0);
```

I think as long as the parameters are `|x| < INT_MAX/2`, all is OK.

---

A *general* solution that handles all combinations of inputs needs careful handling.

[Edit]

As OP does not need a full range solution  (and being a bit lazy), I'll postpone digging up and posting the general solution.

Comment: You are right, my screen is 320x240, thats why i did not take this into consideration. Thank you for your input